# How to load base64 audio locally on cordova mobile?

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, mobile, base64

I've been trying to load an audio file already encoded in base64 but to no avail. I can load encoded images easily, but I can't do it with audio. The example I found with cordova audio is passing url link to the asset folder, but I tried that and it didn't work.

Is there a way to play an audio file encoded in base64 directly?

Answer (score 2):

I tried cordova-plugin-media but it seems to work only with files and not with base64 code.

Finally I found this solutions:

SOLUTION 1:

```
var src = "data:audio/mp3;base64," + your_base64_code;
document.write("<audio preload='auto' autoplay><source src='" + src + "' /></audio>");
```

SOLUTION 2:

1) Convert the base64 code to an audio files, saving it in the cache folder.
You can read this article to do it: [How to create an audio file from a mp3 base64 string on the device with Cordova](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/279/how-to-create-an-audio-file-from-a-mp3-base64-string-on-the-device-with-cordova)

You can use as target folder: *cordova.file.cacheDirectory*

For example:

```
saveBase64AsAudioFile(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, "audiofile.mp3", your_base64_code, "audio/mp3");
```

2) Use the cordova-plugin-media to play the created file:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   var src = cordova.file.cacheDirectory + "audiofile.mp3";
   var media = new Media(src);
   media.play();
}, 2000);
```

- Use setTimeout to be sure that the files is already created.